# lessc.cmd cannot find @import file, path resolves fine?

Tags: less, webstorm, css-import

[image]

The above code displays the following error:

```
cmd.exe /D /C call C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/npm/lessc.cmd --no-color style.less
FileError: '/styles/vars.less' wasn't found. Tried - /styles/vars.less,D:\projects\ui\themes\default\styles\vars.less in D:\projects\ui\themes\default\style.less on line 1, column 1:
1 @import "/styles/vars.less";
2 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

But if I change the path to something invalid:

[image]

Now I see "Cannot resolve file" as well as the unresolved variable.  Is this a bug or something I'm doing wrong?

Here is the folder structure of the relevant files:

```
(root)/
├── styles/
│   ├── vars.less
├── themes/
│   ├── default/
│       └── style.less (the file with the error)
```

Comment: "FileError: '/styles/vars.less' wasn't found." doesn't look like IDE error. Can you attach a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Updated, looks like it's actually a less compiler error. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: does it help if you add `--include-path=$ProjectFileDir$` to file watcher arguments? looks like lessc can't resolve the passed absolute path

Comment: Looks like that did fix it.  I've been using this same setup for a year. Any idea what is causing this in this particular project?

Comment: not sure; may be caused by lessc and project located on different drives

Comment: The so called `root` is the root of your drive or the root of your project? From command line, `/` will mean the root of the drive. If the project is located in a subfolder it will fail. Make the import relative to the compiled file `@import "../../styles/vars.less`